# Cannot use methods of SubClass Y after pushing it into std::stack<ParentClass> (C++)

Tags: c++, class, c++11, stack, subclass

I am trying to create my own programming language. The *Virtual Machine* for that language is going to use a *data stack* where all the objects are going to be pushed to and popped from.

Now, obviously, `std::stack` only allows elements of the **same type** to be pushed into it, thus I have created a very general `Obj` class that is going to be the parent class for all of the other datatypes like `Num`, `Chr`, etc...

```c
class Obj
{
    std::string type;

    public:
    void set_type(std::string type) { this->type = type; }
    std::string get_type() { return this->type; }
};
```

To give you an example of the `Num` subclass:

```c
class Num : public Obj
{
    double value;

    public:
    Num (double value)
    {
        this->set_type("num");
        this->value = value;
    }

    double get_value() { return this->value; }
};
```

The problem became apparent later on... I was writing the EMIT_CONST function that is supposed to pop the element from the top of the stack and print it to the standard output. To give you more info about the way things look:

```c
std::stack<Obj> data;

void emit_const(std::stack<Obj> &data)
{
    if ( data.empty() ) return; // some error checking

    std::string type = data.top().get_type();

    if (type == "bln")
    {
        Bln bln = data.top(); data.pop();
        std::cout << bln.get_value() ? "true" : "false";
    }

    else if (type == "chr")
    {
        Chr chr = data.top(); data.pop();
        std::cout << chr.get_value();
    }

    // ... and so on for the rest of the types
}
```

When I tried to compile that, GNU g++ compiler gave me an error:

```
conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Obj> >::value_type {aka Obj}’ 
to non-scalar type ‘Bln’ requested
         Bln bln = data.top(); data.pop();
```

This same error message was given for every line of code where I'm basically trying to interpret `Obj` as its subclass like `Bln` or `Num` in order to be able to use their methods that are not defined in the general `Obj` class.

As I understand, after pushing any instance of `Obj`'s subclass like `Bln` into the `std::stack<Obj>`, this instance gets stripped off of its methods and members that are not declared in the parent `Obj` class (I infered that based on the fact that the line `std::string type = data.top().get_type();` doesn't generate an error). Such behaviour is reasonable from the C++ point of view. Nevertheless, I still need to make this thing work and I need to be able to use those items' methods when they are popped out. Please help me resolve that in an efficient way! Thanks in advance.

If you wish to look at the general code layout: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/sharpvik/scoops/tree/objectify/VirtualMachine)

Comment: Another key term to look for is *Object Slicing*.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here: `get_type` needs to be virtual and when you use `std::stack<Obj>`, it removes all the data.

When you use `std::stack<Obj>`, it first casts it to an Obj and removes all the properties of num. When you try to cast it back to its original type, it can't because it only stored the Obj's properties and not the subclasses information. In order to fix this, you must either keep a reference to it (`std::stack<Obj&>`) or have it make a copy and store it on the heap (`std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Obj>>`) so that it can keep the information from the subclasses.

Secondly, you need to declare `get_type` as virtual. Virtual is a keyword that tells the class to store information that tells what type it is. This allows the program to call the right method. If you don't use this, the parent classes version (Obj) will always be called instead.